# Vulkan compute shader copy from image2D result to sampler2D for next frame

Tags: synchronization, vulkan, compute-shader, render-to-texture, renderdoc

I am trying to post process image with compute shader, and use previous frame's color in the current computations. I need sampler2D to access interpolation operations, even though it doesn't seem like so in the following simple example. I update current in-out 'color' with following shader:

```
#version 460
#extension GL_GOOGLE_include_directive : enable

layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;

layout(binding = 0, set = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D color;
layout(binding = 1, set = 0) uniform sampler2D previous_color;
void main()
{
    ivec2 xy_int = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    ivec2 size = imageSize(color);
    vec2 xy_float = vec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x / size.x, gl_GlobalInvocationID.y / size.y);
    
    vec3 sample_color = imageLoad(color, xy_int).xyz;
    // Frame 2 and onwards
    vec3 prev_color = texture(previous_color, xy_float).xyz;
    
    vec3 mixed_color = mix(sample_color, prev_color, 0.5);
    imageStore(color, vec4(mixed_color, 1.0f), xy_int);
}
```

After dispatching:

1. I transition the image layouts using pipeline barriers
2. Use vkCmdCopyImage to copy the 'color' image to 'previous_color'
3. Transition back the layout to be ready to be used in the next frame

All of this (including the compute shader dispatch) is done in one command buffer. However, inspecting the 'previous_color' as input texture with Renderdoc, I see that the texture is always black and doesn't exist. I can also inspect the copy event, which shows that the copy was successful and 'previous_color' image has the correct color.

Am I approaching copying wrong here? Why is the copied image not available as texture the next frame? I am not getting any Vulkan validation layer errors with my setup.

I assume something is messed up with my synchronization, but cannot find out what.
I am not using queue families. More specifically, my layout transitions are:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer()

...

vkCmdDispatch() // the example_shader.comp above

...


color ImageMemoryBarrier with:
access flags:       VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT -> VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT
layout transition:  VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL
stage:              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT -> VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT

prev_color ImageMemoryBarrier with:
access flags:       VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT -> VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT
layout transition:  VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
stage:              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT -> VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT

vkCmdCopyImage(color, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, previous_color, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL)

prev_color ImageMemoryBarrier with:
access flags:       VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT -> VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT
layout transition:  VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL
stage:              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT -> VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT

color ImageMemoryBarrier with:
access flags:       VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT -> VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT
layout transition:  VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL
stage:              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT -> VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT

...

vkEndCommandBuffer()
```

The Sampler2D was created with:

```
VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo{};
samplerInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_FALSE;
samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = 0;
samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_TRANSPARENT_BLACK;
samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
samplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
samplerInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
samplerInfo.maxLod = 0.0f;
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't realize that the 'previous_color' is actually usable now! There might actually not be any errors other than a bug in Renderdoc, not displaying the previous_color as input texture as black. This requires little further exploration, as I did change barriers to be more strict than before. I was only looking with renderdoc, without realizing the end result was what I was looking for already.

Comment: Why use compute and images at all? You could do all this in fragment shaders using samplers everywhere, and likely go faster. You're not using any of the algorithmic features that need compute shaders (shared memory, etc).

Comment: Beyond that, it's going to be hard to help without a more complete minimal reproducer.

Comment: I think that we are missing some information in your example: Does the compute shader invocation happen between the last `color ImageMemoryBarrier` and the first `color ImageMemoryBarrier` from your sync-listing? Do you maybe swap the `color` and the `prev_color` images at some point, s.t. `color` becomes `prev_color` or something like that (which could result in situations where `READ` and `WRITE` flags in barriers have been messed up)? Does your `sampler2D previous_color` have mipmaps and which filter modes is it configured with?

Comment: @solidpixel I understand that this could be possible to do in fragment shader, but on the current renderer I am using I am interested if it can be done in compute shader. So does it sound correct on high level, that I should be able to copy an image at the end of the same command buffer that writes the colors? And transfer the layout back so that it is usable as texture?

Comment: @j00hi I edited the question with requested information.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to confirm synchronization issues is to temporarily add more synchronization to force serial execution. If it starts working then it's a sync issue.

```
// Issue earlier work

vkQueueSubmit()
vkQueueWaitIdle()

// Issue copy image

vkQueueSubmit()
vkQueueWaitIdle()

// Issue follow on work
```

If it's still black it's not a sync issue.

Comment: I tested this out, and now the 'previous_color' gets filled with color! I wonder if two queue submits is the only approach, or could I somehow utilize the synchronization flags.

Comment: I.e., is it correct that with the `vkQueueWaitIdle` you get color values in `previous_color` in your **compute shader**, but without it, you don't? If so, what are you doing with `previous_color` _before_ the call to `vkCmdDispatch`? Didn't you write that the `vkCmdCopyImage` produces the correct result, but just your compute shader does not get the data in `previous_color` which you are expecting? (Or am I misunderstanding something?)

Comment: Yes, it is correct that without the `vkQueueWaitIdle`, the next run of the compute shader does not have `previous_color`. In a sense, I am not doing anything for the `previous_color` before the dispatch (except bind it's ImageView to the shader when building the pipeline), as I am expecting it to be good-to-go from the end of previous frame (copy and transfers).

Comment: What happens if you just put a `vkQueueWaitIdle()` _before_  the queue submit that contains both, the compute shader invocation and the image copy? I.e. so that the `vkQueueWaitIdle()` happens immediately before the compute shader invocation? Do you get data in `previous_color` then?

Comment: vkQueueWaitIdle did not affect the result at all